# Count number of zeros after decimal point in Java

Tags: java

How can I count the 0s after a decimal point? For example, `0.0003` has 3 zeros, `0.03` has 1 zero and `0.00000045` has 6 zeros.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  If you want someone to help you, please read on how to ask a question first - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask  .  This isn't even a question. Yes, I can count also.  What are you asking?

Comment: Do you want to count the number of zero after the 0 or you want to convert a number to a scientific notation like 4E-3 ? I can see that the current title is slightly different from the one I read in spanish.

Comment: Convert it to a string and count the '0's and subtract one if it's between 0 and 1?  I dunno, never really thought about it and there's probably a better way.  That said, you should be showing some code you've already tried if you want people to respect you as a questioner

Comment: @OldProgrammer my guess is that it's a bad translation from spanish to english so give him a chance.

Comment: count 0 point there after

Comment: Si no se hablar ingles

Comment: Don't edit this question to something *completely* different. Ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to keep multiplying by 10 until your number is greater than one; then count how many times you had to multiply by 10 and subtract 1.

```
double num = 0.00000045;

int zeros = 0;
while (num < 1) {
    num *= 10;
    zeros++;
}
zeros -= 1;

System.out.println(zeros);
```

```
6
```

If you have other non-zero digits before the decimal point, you can trim those off with something like `num = num % 1`. If your number is negative, then just take its absolute value.

Comment: There is something missing if you have `1.0003`, `10.0003` ... thought I upvoted....

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Read the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: then what about negative number? :)

Comment: That said, this algorithm is very linear and if we'd have 250 "0" after the decimal it could take a while. In C I guess we could just extract the value directly from the float/double using bitwize operation. I guess it should be possible to do the same in Java but i'm not certain.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix How would you even do that in C?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision here, one might only have to extract the exponent byte for 32bit float and for 64bit I don't know, while I think now back to it that it's a bit more complex. Interesting though..

Comment: Exacto ESTOY desarrollando un Código de punto flotante sin utilizar el DecimalFormat

Answer (score 3):

```
(int)Math.log10(1/(x%1))
```

I think this short formula should work correct [for positive x - if it can be negative, we add taking of absolute value]  - or there are some cases when it doesn't?

Comment: consider one cse 10.000200300

Comment: Great answer, but there is one thing missing. You have to use 'floor' to get the number of leading zeros.
(int) Math.floor(Math.log10(1/(x%1)))
And as OP said, make sure that x is positive by using 'abs'.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using Strings. First get a substring of digits after decimal point. Then convert that into a char array. Then loop through it and count the number of zeroes.

Comment: Could fail to work sadly because some `locale` use different decimal delimiter. Using number arithmetic is the best solution IMO.

Comment: you can use ROOT locale which always uses a dot as a decimal separator

Comment: Also it's worth considering the overhead of a `String`, comparing to `Double` or `Float`.